# python socket; my connection is breaking my data stream

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to connect to a socket server and view/download a temperature readings polling stream

i.e.

```
72.81
72.83
72.79
72.85
```

But what I get are float values split in half.

```
72
.35
72
.36
72
.36
72
.37
72
.38
72
.38
72
.38
72
.39
```

How do I output unbroken float values from a socket connection?

client code:

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

    s.connect(("192.168.1.249" , 8080))
    s.sendall(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: webcode.me\r\nAccept: text/html\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n")

    while True:

        data = s.recv(1024)

        if not data:
            break

        print(data.decode())
```

Comment: Try to add `end=""` to the "print" call. If this doesn't work, the sender produces the data in this bad format.

Comment: You are using the HTTP protocol with an HTTP server but you're not using an HTTP client to communicate. You can read about some builtin packages [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/internet.html), but I think most people prefer the third-party [requests library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Comment: @brad in addition to what MichaelButscher said, you should read the [`print()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for why `end=""` is needed

Comment: if server sends new line after every temperature then you should read data until you get new line and then display it. Socket doesn't have to send all data at once and you need some method/rule to recognize end of data. And rules which help you work with data are called "protocol". For example protocol HTTP has rule: end of headers is `\r\n\r\n` - so (as I know) it uses loop with  `read(1)` until it gets  `\r\n\r\n`

Comment: @MichaelButscher That plus adding a \n to the output of the server worked. Thank you!